# Putting an error function in angular javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My javascript function is working in angular, but I want to have an error function to determine of there is an error when a bad request is sent. How could I put the error function in this kind of format of code in javascript? Thanks in advance to those who want to help me.

```js
$scope.submitLogin = function()
   { 
       
    var request = {};
    request.url = '/account/users/login';
    request.method = 'POST';
    request.data = angular.toJson($scope.students);
   
    var onSuccess = function(data, status, headers, config, statusText)
    { 
      alert('success!');
         $location.url('/examdirection/'); 
    };   
    httpRequest(request, $scope.response, onSuccess);
   };
```

Comment: What do you mean by bad request is being sent? Also do you expect to handle error response from server?

Comment: Could you please show `httpRequest` function. Processing error response from the server should be somewhere there.

Comment: Sorry to my last explanation, Yes I mean handling an error response from server. Actually that function is working and I put a condition in my controller like if response sent this http_response_code(200). This time I want to know how to put that error handling in a javascript.